# Python slow on for-loops and hundreds of attribute lookups. Use Numba?

Tags: python, jit, numba, kdtree

i am working on a simple showcase SPH (smoothed particle hydrodynamics, not relevant here though) implementation in python. The code works, but the execution is kinda sluggish. I often have to compare individual particles with a certain amount of neighbours. In an earlier implementation i kept all particle positions and all distances-to-each-existing-particle in large numpy arrays -> to a certain point this was pretty fast. But visually not pleasing and n**2. Now i want it clean and simple with classes + kdTree to speed up the neighbour search.

this all happens in my global Simulation-Class. Additionally there's a class called "particle" that contains all individual informations. i create hundreds of instances before and loop through them.

```
 def calculate_density(self):
    #Using scipys advanced nearest neighbour seach magic
    tree = scipy.spatial.KDTree(self.particle_positions)

    #here we go... loop through all existing particles. set attributes..
    for particle in self.my_particles:

        #get the indexes for the nearest neighbours
        particle.index_neighbours = tree.query_ball_point(particle.position,self.h,p=2)


        #now loop through the list of neighbours and perform some additional math
        particle.density = 0
        for neighbour in particle.index_neighbours:


            r = np.linalg.norm(particle.position - self.my_particles[neighbour].position) 
            particle.density +=  particle.mass *  (315/(64*math.pi*self.h**9)) *(self.h**2-r**2)**3
```

i timed 0.2717630863189697s for only 216 particles.

Now i wonder: what to do to speed it up? 
Most tools online like "Numba" show how they speed up math-heavy individual functions. I dont know which to choose. On a sidenode, i cannot even get Numba to work in this case. I get a looong error message. And i hoped it is as simple as slapping "@jit" in front of it.

I know its the loops with the attribute calls that crush my performance anyway - not the math or the neighbour search. Sadly iam a novice to programming and i liked the clean approach i got to work here :( any thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

These kind of loop-intensive calculations are slow in Python. In these cases, the first thing you want to do is to see if you can vectorize these operations and get rid of the loops. Then actual calculations will be done in C or Fortran libraries and you will get a lot of speed up. If you can do it usually this is the way to go, since it is much easier to maintain your code.

Some operations, however, are just inherently loop-intensive. In these cases using Cython will help you a lot - you can usually expect 60X+ speed up when you cythonize your loop. I also had similar experiences with numba - when my function becomes complicated, it failed to make it faster, so usually I just use Cython.

Coding in Cython is not too bad - much easier than actually code in C because you can access numpy arrays easily via memoryviews. Another advantage is that it is pretty easy to parallelize the loop with openMP, which can gives you additional 4X+ speedups (of course, depending on the number of cores you have in your machine), so your code can be hundreds times faster.

One issue is that to get the optimal speed, you have to remove all the python calls inside your loop, which means you cannot call numpy/scipy functions. So you have to convert `tree.query_ball_point` and `np.linalg.norm` part to Cython for optimal speed.

Comment: i tried vectorizing before but i cant see how i should do it now that i make use of the kDTree - each particle has a unique amount of neighbours. No idea how to store this informations easily in one array. probably too advanced for me ;-) Interesting thoughts on Cython. If its just for the fact that its looping faster - iam in.

Comment: It sounds like Cython is the way to go. I get into this kind of problems all the time. Learning Cython can be worth the investment.

Comment: "So you have to convert tree.query_ball_point ... to Cython for optimal speed. " this sounds frightening and non-trivial, no?

Comment: Yes I had to replicate scipy's bisect algorithm once because of this once. You have to check the actual source code of those functions to see if they are feasible. A good news is that you already have the working Python code, so replicating it in Cython would be easier, since you already have the test case (you can check if your function yields the same value as the Python one).

Comment: And what makes Cython here more suitable than Numba? Both of them are equally able to compile loops. With the additional options regarding metaprogramming due to JIT compiling, I tend to always choose Numba over Cython.

Comment: As I said, numba hasn't worked that well for me when the calculation inside a loop becomes very complex (calling other functions, etc). My experience with numba is limited comparing to that with cython though.